# Is it possible to refresh a portion of the ui table view without refresh other cells?

Tags: uitableview, refresh, tableview, partial-page-refresh

Is it possible to refresh some cells without refreshing other cells in a table view?

I need to delete and insert and add some cells simultaneously. For that i want to refresh the table frequently.

[self.tableView reloadData];

- This code is used to refresh all the cells in table i think. I'm not sure about this. Because my table contains huge amount of cell which may take some time to reload all cells.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, try `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`. See also: `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, `deletetRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.